# Ruby delayed_job gem how to stop process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, scheduled-tasks, delayed-job

I am currently using the delayed_job_active_record gem to run some scheduled tasks on a long run basis. The processes run in the background on a separate worker dyno on heroku and rarely go wrong but in some cases I would like to be able to stop a process mid run. I have been running the processes locally and because of the setup I have, the scheduled tasks only kick off the process which is essentially a very long loop.

Using

```rb
bin/delayed_job stop
```

only stops the jobs but since the process has started, it doesn't top this.
Because of this, I can't seem to stop the process once it has got going without restarting the entire dyno. This seems a bit excessive but is my only option at the moment.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anyway to interrupt it without essentially killing the process like you are doing. I would usually delete the job record in the database and *then* terminate the worker running it so it doesn't just retry the job (if you've got retries enabled for that job).

Another option... Since you know it's long running and, I imagine, has multiple steps... Modularize the operation and/or add periodic checks for a 'cancelled' flag you put somewhere in the model(s). If you detect the cancelled request, you can then give up and do any cleanup needed. This is probably preferred anyway so you can manage what happens when it's aborted more explicitly.

Comment: I really like this concept of a cancelled flag. Guessing I could set up an operations model and could update these through an admin portal. Pause or cancel the operations when needed.